# What happen with my database in order to insert to mysql

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-insert

i have table called discount_star_member_periode both in my database production and my local. the schema is also same like this :

```
id  int(10) unsigned    NO  PRI     auto_increment
product_id  int(10) unsigned    NO  MUL     
startDate   datetime    NO          
endDate datetime    YES         
status  tinyint(4)  NO      1   
value_discount_star_member  decimal(10,2)   NO          
max_quantity    int(11) NO      0
```

what makes me confused is when i run this query

```
insert into discount_star_member_periode (product_id, startDate, EndDate, Status, value_discount_star_member, max_quantity) values (1681 ,'2021-04-08 15:00:00' ,'2021-04-15 15:00:00', 1,20 ,3);
insert into discount_star_member_periode (product_id, startDate, EndDate, Status, value_discount_star_member, max_quantity) values (1682 ,'2021-04-08 15:00:00' ,'2021-04-15 15:00:00', 1,20 ,3);
insert into discount_star_member_periode (product_id, startDate, EndDate, Status, value_discount_star_member, max_quantity) values (1505 ,'2021-04-08 15:00:00' ,'2021-04-15 15:00:00', 1,15 ,2);
insert into discount_star_member_periode (product_id, startDate, EndDate, Status, value_discount_star_member, max_quantity) values (1879 ,'2021-04-08 15:00:00' ,'2021-04-15 15:00:00', 1,20 ,2);
insert into discount_star_member_periode (product_id, startDate, EndDate, Status, value_discount_star_member, max_quantity) values (1881 ,'2021-04-08 15:00:00' ,'2021-04-15 15:00:00', 1,20 ,1);
insert into discount_star_member_periode (product_id, startDate, EndDate, Status, value_discount_star_member, max_quantity) values (336 ,'2021-04-08 15:00:00' ,'2021-04-15 15:00:00', 1,20 ,3);
insert into discount_star_member_periode (product_id, startDate, EndDate, Status, value_discount_star_member, max_quantity) values (1610 ,'2021-04-08 15:00:00' ,'2021-04-15 15:00:00', 1,25 ,4);
insert into discount_star_member_periode (product_id, startDate, EndDate, Status, value_discount_star_member, max_quantity) values (347 ,'2021-04-08 15:00:00' ,'2021-04-15 15:00:00', 1,20 ,2);
insert into discount_star_member_periode (product_id, startDate, EndDate, Status, value_discount_star_member, max_quantity) values (60 ,'2021-04-08 15:00:00' ,'2021-04-15 15:00:00', 1,25 ,2);
insert into discount_star_member_periode (product_id, startDate, EndDate, Status, value_discount_star_member, max_quantity) values (1659 ,'2021-04-08 15:00:00' ,'2021-04-15 15:00:00', 1,35 ,2);
insert into discount_star_member_periode (product_id, startDate, EndDate, Status, value_discount_star_member, max_quantity) values (1752 ,'2021-04-08 15:00:00' ,'2021-04-15 15:00:00', 1,30 ,2);
insert into discount_star_member_periode (product_id, startDate, EndDate, Status, value_discount_star_member, max_quantity) values (1910 ,'2021-04-08 15:00:00' ,'2021-04-15 15:00:00', 1,18 ,2);
insert into discount_star_member_periode (product_id, startDate, EndDate, Status, value_discount_star_member, max_quantity) values (1906 ,'2021-04-08 15:00:00' ,'2021-04-15 15:00:00', 1,30 ,2);
```

in my database production, column `EndDate` always filled with +1 day from `startDate`, Yet, when i test it in my local database, the return was true and the same with the queries. so what makes this happen?

Comment: Any triggers on this table?

Comment: It works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24350d/1, so I think there should be something else

Comment: FWIW, I find the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE more useful than the output of DESCRIBE

Comment: i found out that the issue was on the triggers behind the table, thankyou sir @P.Salmon